# Extending/overriding in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a small game using JavaScript and `<canvas>` but first I want to nail the "correct" or at least common approach to working with Objects.

One topic I am having trouble understanding in particular is how I could implement `overriding` of method.

When I create an Object, I may have this:

```
function MyObject()
{
    var base = {};

    base.i = 0;
    base.update = function()
    {
        base.i ++;
    }

   return base;
}
```

Then when I create another Object that should start with the same members, I use this:

```
function AnotherObject()
{
    var base = new MyObject();

    base.j = 0;

    return base;
}
```

I want to add more content to `AnotherObject.update()` while still running the logic I have in `MyObject.update()`, but when I do this within `AnotherObject()`:

```
base.update = function()
{
    j ++;
}
```

Then I of course lose the logic I added in `MyObject.update()`.

How can I write `AnotherObject.update()` so that it also calls the original `update()` method defined by `MyObject`?

Comment: You need to learn how to use an Object's prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you read this excellent [excellent MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). It will enlighten you.

You can achieve subclassing this way:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.i = 0;
}

MyObject.prototype.update = function() {
  this.i++;
}

function AnotherObject() {
  MyObject.call(this);
  this.j = 0;
}

AnotherObject.prototype = new MyObject;

AnotherObject.prototype.constructor = AnotherObject;

AnotherObject.prototype.update = function() {
  MyObject.prototype.update.call(this);
  this.j++;
}

obj = new AnotherObject();
console.log(obj.i); //0
console.log(obj.j); //0

obj.update();
console.log(obj.i); //1
console.log(obj.j); //1

console.log(obj instanceof MyObject) //true
console.log(obj instanceof AnotherObject) //true
```

Comment: There's a problem with this, you assign and then reassign `AnotherObject.prototype`, instead of adding properties to it after the first assignment. Also `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)` is almost always preferable to `B.prototype = new A()` -- http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: You are right about the prototype part, edited it. `Object.create` is also preferable but I wanted to provide a simple verbose example.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for zzzzBov's comment.  You're using `base` when you should be using `prototype`.  Not within the constructor function, but rather after the constructor function to further refine the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyObject() {
    this.value = 5;
}
MyObject.prototype.update = function() {
     this.value++;
}
Var newObject = new MyObject();
newObject.update =function() {
    value--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you should follow prototype based inheritance. That is the right way to do it.

But as a solution to what you have done so far you can do as shown below

```
function MyObject() {
    var base = {};
    base.i = 0;
    base.update = function () {
        this.i++;
    }
    base.show = function () {
        console.log("i is " + this.i);
    }
    return base;
}

function AnotherObject() {
    var base = new MyObject();
    base.j = 0;
    var update = base.update;  // proxy variable that refers to original `update`
    base.update = function () {
        update.call(this);  // invoke original `update`
        this.j++;
    }
    var show = base.show;  // proxy variable that refers to original `show`
    base.show = function () {
        show.call(this);   // invoke original `show`
        console.log("j is " + this.j);
    }
    return base;
}

var t = AnotherObject();
t.update();
t.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - knowing how to keep a reference to an original method helps me out :)

Comment: Knowing how to use prototype based inheritance would help even more. This is really not too good.

Comment: You should really learn prototype based inheritance. This approach is inefficient; it creates 4 functions per AnotherObject instance...